# ui-router sticky state refresh when closing modal with nested states on top of nested views

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-router-extras

following is a subset of my app structure along with modal structure.
App structure:

```
.state ('A',{
  abstract: true,
  sticky:true,
  views:{
  '@ ':{  
    template:'<div ui-view="container-a"></div> <div ui-view="container-b"></div>',                                                             controller: BController
     }
   }
})
```

//a child of A which is defined dot notation (.) in same config file

```
.state(A.a,{
  views:{
    'container-a':{templateUrl:'some.html'},
    'container-b':{templateUrl:'anothertemplte.html'}
  }
});
```

in my second config file I have similar state config but here state B is child of state A.a which is defined by parent attribute as I did not wanted to have long string representing inheritance hierarchy (A.a.B and so one as i have series of state nested similarly )

```
.state ('B',{
  abstract: true,
  parent: 'A.a',
  views:{
   '@':
     {
       template: <div ui-view="abc"></div><div ui-view="xyz"> /div>,
       controller:BController
     }
   }
})
.state(B.b,{
  views:{
   'abc':{templateUrl:'some.html'}, 
   'xyz':{templateUrl:'anothertemplte.html'}
  }
});
```

Modal structure:
I have a abstract global modal having a close button and a ui-sref hosting for other templats inside that like below:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('global-modal',{ 
    url: '',
    abstract: true,
    onEnter:  ['$modal', function($modal) { 
       $modal.open({
        template: '<html for close button> <div ui-sref="childModal" ',
        controller: 'GlobalController',
        backdrop:'static',
        keyboard:false 
        }) 
     }] 
  })  
.controller('GlobalController',  ['$scope', '$state', '$previousState', '$modalInstance',
  function ($scope, $state, $previousState, $modalInstance) {
    $previousState.memo("modalInvoker"); 
      $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        $previousState.go("modalInvoker"); 
      };
  }]);
```

then have a 2 nested states which gets load in ui-view=childModal of gloabal modal as follows
( in short)

```
state( 'C',{
parent: global-mdoal,
 views:{'childModal':{template:'C_template.html', controller: 'CController' } }
})
state('D',{
parent: C,
views:{'childModal':{template:'D_template.html', controller: 'DController' } }
```

**now the issue:**

if I am in B.b state and open the modal it will load C and by closing of it the sticky works fine, but if again open modal from B.b and this time navigate from C to sub state D behind the backdrop it will navigate to my parent state (A.a) whoever closing the modal will navigate me to B.b but it will refresh the page.
(if I do this navigation in modal from C to D on top of A.a which is my top state it wont refresh the page as navigation from C to D always load the A.a behind the backdrop, so there is no refresh when doing transition in modal on top of top state A.a but transition inside modal on top of sub states of A.a like B.b etc will cause the refersh and sticky wont work [even tried put sticky:true in each state but again same behavior]

Answer (score 0):

C state you defined "golbal-mdoal" check if your code is wrong or if you typed wrong here